# Replace unique values in col with list - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm hoping to replace unique values in a pandas df with values in a list. Rather than using hard coded values with `replace()`, I'm hoping to use the ordering of unique values. Using the `df` below, I want to use `lst` and with unique values in `Val3`. So for the first unique value use `lst[0]` and the 2nd use `lst[1]`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Val1': [1, 4, 7, 10, 12, 12],
               'Val2': ['12', '14', '14', '13', '15', '15'],
               'Val3': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'X']})

lst = ['A','B']
```

Note:

I can't use:

```
df['Val3'] = df['Val3'].replace('X','A')
df['Val3'] = df['Val3'].replace('Y','B')
```

Because the values in `Val3` will vary, I want this to be dynamic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

replace takes a list so you can take the `unique` of that series and replace with the list (make sure the length of the list matches the length of unique values in the series):

```
df['Val3'] = df['Val3'].replace(df['Val3'].unique(),lst)
#or df['Val3'].replace(dict(zip(df['Val3'].unique(),lst)))
```

---

```
0    A
1    B
2    A
3    B
4    B
5    A
Name: Val3, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

General solution if possible different number of values for replace is create dictionary - here last value `Z` is not replaced:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val1': [1, 4, 7, 10, 12, 12],
               'Val2': ['12', '14', '14', '13', '15', '15'],
               'Val3': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y', 'Z']})

lst = ['A','B']
df['Val3'] = df['Val3'].replace(dict(zip(df['Val3'].unique(),lst)))
print (df)
   Val1 Val2 Val3
0     1   12    A
1     4   14    B
2     7   14    A
3    10   13    B
4    12   15    B
5    12   15    Z
```

If want replace by all values of list by first values and all another vals to same default value use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val1': [1, 4, 7, 10, 12, 12],
               'Val2': ['12', '14', '14', '13', '15', '15'],
               'Val3': ['X', 'Y', 'X', 'Y', 'W', 'Z']})

lst = ['A','B']
df['Val3'] = df['Val3'].map(dict(zip(df['Val3'].unique(),lst))).fillna('Other')
print (df)
   Val1 Val2   Val3
0     1   12      A
1     4   14      B
2     7   14      A
3    10   13      B
4    12   15  Other
5    12   15  Other
```

If always match number of unique values by number of values of lists and perfromance is important with numpy indexing - converting `lst` to aray with [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html):

```
lst = ['A','B']
df['Val3'] = np.array(lst)[pd.factorize(df['Val3'].to_numpy())[0]]
print (df)
   Val1 Val2 Val3
0     1   12    A
1     4   14    B
2     7   14    A
3    10   13    B
4    12   15    B
5    12   15    B
```